# How can Mathematica be used interpret a Taylor series as a function or combination of known function?

Tags: functions

Wolfram Alpha, which seems to use the same computation engine as *Mathematica*, can recognize Taylor series summations as functions. For instance, it could recognize $$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ as the exponential function, $e^x$.

How could this be done in *Mathematica* starting from a blank document?

Comment: Your equation is wrong as it does not involve the change of $k$.

Comment: @David, please do not (ab)use MathJax for italicizing things in titles.

Comment: @JM:  Why not?  My friend Stephen Wolfram always argued for italicizing "Mathematica" in such documents and postings, and the traditional method of using asterisks does not seem to work in titles.  Again:  Why not?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Well, we no longer italicize Mathematica (try typing it in a recent version), so that argument has gone away.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Because typesetting *Mathematica* in MathJax makes it a variable.  But we all know *Mathematica* is not a variable: it is a CAS.

Comment: OK.  If the word is from a Mathematica developer, well... I'll relent.

Comment: @David, Quantum Dot already gave my reasoning. If there is math stuff in the title, use MathJax by all means, but it is not intended for forcing formatting where there is none. Also, even tho it is as Itai says that the italicization is now old-fashioned, I still tend to do so in comments and text. Just not on the title, please. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just like any other sum, power series can be computed using the `Sum` function, with limits at `Infinity`:

```
Sum[x^k/k!, {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

This produces the answer $e^x$.